# Github code preview looks odd

Tags: github

[On GitHub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvZCH.png)

why does the code look like this?
It looks fine in all the code editors out there

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+M characters present in a file in linux, when originally the file came from Windows environment.

> You may need to remove Ctrl+M characters, when you import a text file from MS-DOS (or MS-Windows), and forget to transfer it in ASCII or text mode. Here are several ways to do it; pick the one you are most comfortable with.
>
> The easiest way is probably to use the stream editor sed to remove the ^M characters. Type this command: % sed -e "s/^M//" filename > newfilename
>   To enter ^M, type CTRL-V, then CTRL-M. That is, hold down the CTRL key then press V and M in succession.
>
> You can also do it in vi: % vi filename
>   Inside vi [in ESC mode] type: :%s/^M//g
>   To enter ^M, type CTRL-V, then CTRL-M. That is, hold down the CTRL key then press V and M in succession.
>
> You can also do it inside Emacs. To do so, follow these steps:
>   Go to the beginning of the document
>   Type: M-x replace-string RET C-q C-m RET RET
>   where "RET" means  and C-q and C-m mean .

Courtesy: https://its.ucsc.edu/unix-timeshare/tutorials/clean-ctrl-m.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir,your answer helped me figure out the root cause. Its caused due to 'line ending'. I simply checked mine, in Pycharm bottom right corner, changed it to LF and pushed the new version on GitHub and it worked.

Comment: if it solved your problem, you could upvote this answer :)

Comment: I did but it won’t be displayed since my reputation is less than 5 sorry 